# How to change text in mat-select when it's collapsed?

Tags: angular

When the user selects some items in **mat-select** and closes its pop-up list, **mat-select** shows text with selected items:

[image: mat-select]

But I need to control this text to show a something like `3 items selected`, `All items selected` and etc because of my **mat-select** implements a pagination and I want to have only one page in memory.

Is it possible in Angular?

Comment: Please add a starting point in code and/or an example what you’ve already tried.

Comment: @Roy, I tried a nothing cuz I don't know how. The Angular material docs about **mat-select** doesn't explain how to control that text. Google didn't help too.

Comment: Here is example from angular-material documentation https://stackblitz.com/angular/voeolyjqldp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.html

Comment: @ArmenStepanyan, wow, so simple, thank you! I googled for few hours without any result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is concept in angular material called ** Customizing the trigger label **

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#customizing-the-trigger-label

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Select with custom trigger text */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-custom-trigger-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-custom-trigger-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-custom-trigger-example.css'],
})
export class SelectCustomTriggerExample {
  toppings = new FormControl();

  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{toppings.value ? toppings.value[0] : ''}}
      <span *ngIf="toppings.value?.length > 1" class="example-additional-selection">
        (+{{toppings.value.length - 1}} {{toppings.value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
      </span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I read this document few times including that section but I decided it's just to show an additional number of selections. I should have looked at source code.